# Reduce floating table vertical space in [H] environment

Tags: tables, spacing

My document contains 5 parts vertically.

- "Header" Contains three minibox placed horizontally.
  Gap filled with
  \hfill.
- Giant row One. Table envoironment, [H] used to located the
  table.
- Giant row Two. Table envoironment, [H] used to located the
  table.
- Giant row Three. Table envoironment, [H] used to located the
  table.
- Giant row Four. Table envoironment, [H] used to located the
  table.

Preamble Section

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[letterpaper, top=0.2in, bottom=0.15in, left=0.25in, right=0.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow,array,varwidth,spreadtab,caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs,caption}
\usepackage{multirow,array,varwidth,spreadtab,}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs,caption}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{table}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\RaggedLeft\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

[image: Where I am currently at]

I was trying to reduce the vertical space between giant rows(floating tables) because there are still two missing rows of data inside row 4 table. I just hide them temporarily to make 5 parts within one page.

Here are my code, some part hiding due to confidentiality.

```
\begin{document}
%%Part 1%%    
\noindent    
\begin{minipage}[t]{.15\textwidth}    
......    
\end{minipage}    
%    
 \hfill    
%    
 \begin{minipage}[c]{.65\textwidth}    
...    
\end{minipage}    
%    
\hfill    
%    
\begin{minipage}[t]{.19\textwidth}    
...    
\end{minipage}    
%%% Part 2 %%%    
\begin{table}[H]    
...    
\end{table}    
%%% Part 3 %%%    
\begin{table}[H]    
...    
\end{table}    
%%% Part 4 %%%    
\begin{table}[H]    
...    
\end{table}    
%%% Part 5 %%%    
\begin{table}[H]    
...    
\end{table}   
\end{document}
```

Tried

```
%\setlength{\textfloatsep}{5pt}    
%\setlength{\floatsep}{10pt plus 3pt minus 5pt}    
%\setlength{\intextsep}{10pt plus 3pt minus 5pt}    
%\addtolength{\fpsep}{-4pt}
```

no help.

Struggled for two days. Still googling and reading ctex online files.

Comment: `[H]` makes the environment not a float so parameters like `\textfloatsep` have no effect. simplest is just to leave a blank line after each  `\end{table}` followed by `\vspace{-5mm}` or whatever adjustment you need.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You just hit me with stone! Thanks a lot. You really made my day. Confused by definition, would learn more from your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[H]` makes the environment not a float so parameters like `\textfloatsep` have no effect.

The simplest thing to do is just to leave a blank line after each `\end{table}` followed by `\vspace{-5mm}` or whatever adjustment you need.

Comment: Perfect answer!